# Android : Post to server success but okhttp return ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

i try post to server with retrofit2 and okhttp v3.4.1, post success save on server, but okhttp respons ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer), i use wifi connection,, and there is my rest client config:

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
    httpClient.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Utils.buildGson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

is anyone know how to solved it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: @T-Heron thanks for your suggestion, this my first question, i will do it